# Missing factor of 1/2 in a multivariable change of variables problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable, jacobian

I am interested in evaluating the integral

$$
\iint_{E} xy dA
$$
where $E$ is the region bounded by $xy = 3$, $xy = 1$, $y = 3x$, and $y = x$.

This gives a region of integration that looks like this:

[image]

Using the substitution $x = u/v$ and $y = v$, we obtain a Jacobian of

$$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}  = 1 \cdot \frac{1}{v} - 0 \cdot \frac{-u}{v^2} = \frac{1}{v} > 0$$

which I think should turn our integral into:

$$
\int_1^3\int_{1}^3 u \cdot \frac{1}{v} du dv = 4 \ln(3).
$$

However, the answer is *supposed* to be $2 \ln (3)$, so I seem to be missing a factor of $1/2$ somewhere.

I changed my bounds by noting that $v = y$, and $y$ goes from $1$ to $3$ in the graph above.  Also, $x = u/v$ implies $u = xv = xy$, and $u = xy$ goes from $1$ to $3$ as well.

**So where is my mistake exactly?**

Comment: "$y$ goes from $1$ to $3$ in the graph above" doesn't mean that you should integrate from $v = 1$ to $v = 3$ after the change of variables - you would then effectively be integrating over [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jt8H.png) region. The problem is that for different values of $u$, the range of values $y$ can take in your region is different. For a fixed $u$, we have $u \le y^2 \le 3u$... so you should integrate from $v = \sqrt u$ to $v = \sqrt{3u}$. (Or instead choose slightly different variables..)

Comment: [A] Here $y$ will not go from 1 to 3 , it is actually $y/x$ which goes from 1 to 3. [B] Hence the limits are over-calculating to include a larger Area. [C] With the Substitution $u=xy$ & $v=y/x$ , the limits will be the rectangle between 1 to 3 & then the integral will work out.

Comment: @Izaak Thank you for this!  If you want to write your comments as answers, I'd be happy to accept it.  Thanks for the graph which cleared this up too.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that "$y$ goes from $1$ to $3$ in the graph above" doesn't mean that you should integrate from $v=1$ to $v=3$ after the change of variables - you would then effectively be integrating over this region:

[image: image of region]

Indeed we can kind of smell that something should be off about that step, because there are many different regions where the range of values of $y$ is $[1, 3]$, but they don't all have the same area.

The problem is that for different values of $u$, the range of values $y$ can take in your region is different. For a fixed $u$, we have $u \le y^2 \le 3u$, so you should integrate from $v = \sqrt u$ to $v = \sqrt{3u}$:

\begin{equation*}
\int_1^3 \int_{v=\sqrt u}^{v=\sqrt{3u}} \frac uv \,\mathrm dv \,\mathrm du
\end{equation*}

which does give the correct answer (it is a pretty confusing coincidence that the answer happens to be half of what you got!). As mentioned in the comments, it's perhaps a bit easier to choose a change of variables which gives a nicer boundary, like $xy$ and $x/y$.

Comment: The bounds are suggested in the problem itself (from Stewart's Calculus), so I didn't come up with them.  Thanks again for the picture as that emphasizes the problem exactly!

Comment: I do not have Stewart Calculus , though I would suspect that the suggested limits are actually **hints** for the easier substitution too !

Comment: @Prem, the exercise in Stewart (I think ex. 19 in 15.10) really does give this change of variables. It's part of a sequence of exercises where the substitution is given. I assume that the point of the exercise is intended to be more to practise the process of changing variables and appropriately transforming the region than to necessarily find the "best" change of variables.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my modification of the given Image :
[image: INTEGRAL AREA]

The Image by user "Izaak van Dongen" is better , I just modified OP Image &  highlighted the Issue with little a bit of text.

Over-view :
OP is calculating with limits $y=1$ & $y=3$ though that will give a larger area. It is $y/x$ which has limits $1$ & $3$.
The Area gives DOUBLE Integral value , $4 \ln 3$ rather than $2 \ln 3$.

Hence the Better Way is the Substitution :
$u=xy$
$v=y/x$
Limits are $1$ & $3$.

### UPDATE :

To make this complete :

Jacobian should be :

$$\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}  = \cdots = \frac{1}{2v}$$

In a "Sense" , **that** is the missing factor of $1/2$ ...

Integral should be :

$$\int_1^3\int_{1}^3 u \cdot \frac{1}{2v} du dv = \cdots = 2 \ln(3)$$